# how to show modal windows dynamically and send data with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to insert modal window html code dynamically upon user click on which item otherwise i load all of the items' modal window code in the html. I also have some inputs in the modal window loading from Flask/Sql and i want to let user update any of them so i need to send data back to python on submit button clicked. But right now because of i have too many modal windows (even though they have separate ids) i couldn't find a way to achieve this

Here is my code:

**routes.py**

```
@app.route('/viewApart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def viewApart():
  apts = []
  getApts = db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM apartments")
  for a in getApts:
      apts.append((a))
  rooms = []
  getRooms = db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM rooms")
  for r in getRooms:
      rooms.append((r))
  return render_template('apartments.html', title=_('Apartments'), apts=apts, rooms=rooms)
```

**apartments.html**

```
....
<section class="container">
<div class="row">
.. below some gallery code to show individual items from apts ..

{% for apt in apts %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="widget__v2 apt-widget rounded-corners box-shadow__v1 white" data-anchor="modalwindow" data-target="edit-apartment{{ apt[0] }}" id="apt{{ apt[0] }}">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <figure class="image h-180">
                    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='_assets/img/apt/{{ apt[0] }}.jpg')}}" alt="" class="image__scaledown">
                </figure>

.. below model window ..

<div id="edit-apartment{{ apt[0] }}" class="modal large">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-inner">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="title">{{ _('Edit Apartment') }}</h3>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-anchor="close-modal" class="modal-close-btn"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="row medium-gutter">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row medium-gutter">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-group-title clearfix">
                                            <label for="apt_display_name">{{ _('Display Name') }}</label>
                                            <div class="lh-24 text__default-grey pull-right" data-tooltip="true" data-tooltip-direction="up" data-multiline="true"
                                                 data-content="..">
                                                <i class="icofont-question-circle"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input id="apt_display_name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ apt[1] }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="apt_number">{{ _('Apt. Number') }}</label>
                                        <input id="apt_number" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ apt[2] }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
.. and so on...

.. and submit button ..
<a href="javascript:void(0);"id="btnSubmit">{{ _('Save Changes') }}</a>
</div>
</section>
```

Right now even with multiple model windows, i can display the current data in modal window, so what i want to achieve this upon clicking on btnSubmit button i need to send all input values back to python so i can update my sql or insert new one. Please let me know if more code is needed..

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a submit button for each of the modal windows?

Comment: @Mortz I know it’s not optimal but yes I have button for each item. I also willing to make it single model window with dynamic data by user clicked which item

Comment: Can you provide what your html looks like for 2 apartments? Do you have a `div` for each apartment which the user clicks to open the modal?

Comment: @Mortz see my edited question please, i did try to make it simple so not included everything but if it's needed i can also supply remaining part of html

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly - a skeleton version of your page would be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>INTRODUCING MY AWESOME SITE AND 2 DIVS YOU CAN CLICK</p>

<div id="apt_1_modal">
  <input id="apt_1_text"></input>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)">Submit</a>
</div>

<div id="apt_2_modal">
  <input id="apt_2_text"></input>
  <a onclick="myFunction(event)">Submit</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You will need `JavaScript` to handle the user interaction - the script would look something like this. You can either append this script directly to your `render_template` output or you can append it as a file.

The script will do 2 things - first capture what your user is inputting and second, send that data over to `flask`

```
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
//FIRST WE CAPTURE THE VALUE THAT THE USER INPUTS
let userInput = {toSend: e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.value}

//THEN WE SEND IT TO THE FLASK BACKEND USING AJAX (Fetch API)
fetch("/api/path/to/flask/route", {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify(userInput)
}
</script>
```

Now you need a function that can handle the `userInput` data

**Backend**

```
from flask import Flask, request #import main Flask class and request object
@app.route('/api/path/to/flask/route', methods=['POST'])
def capture_userinput():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    recd_data = req_data['toSend']
    your_code_to_push_data_to_db(recd_data) #Depends on your ORM/DB
```

I hope I have given you an idea of how to go about - You will most certainly have to change the way to capture `userInput`, tweak the `fetch` call and send/capture additional data in your `flask` api.